# Как вставить значение из callback в message.SuccesfullPayment?

Tags: telebot, python-telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Можно ли вставить значение из callback в message.SuccesfullPayment?И как это сделать?

Мой код на этот хендлер:

```
@router.message(F.successful_payment)
async def successful_payment(message: Message):
    print("Перевод прошел успешно:")
    print('payment_info')
    payment_info = message.successful_payment
    for k, v in payment_info:
        print(f"{k} = {v}")

    await message.answer(
                           f"Оплата на сумму {message.successful_payment.total_amount // 100} {message.successful_payment.currency} прошла успешно!\n\nХорошего <b>Вам</b> настроения!")

    await callback.message.answer_location(latitude=47.504262, longitude=19.066605)
```

Мне нужно чтобы после успешной оплаты выдавало локацию из db (latitude & longitude),или подскажите как сделать функцию которая будет запускаться вместе с `successful_payment`.